# How do I jump to a breakpoint within GDB?

Tags: debugging, console, gdb

I set a breakpoint, which worked fine.

Is there a way to jump immediately to that breakpoint without using "next" or "step"?

Using "next" or "step", it takes really long to get to the final breakpoint.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Just press **c**. It will continue execution until the next breakpoint.

You can also disable intermediate breakpoints by using `disable #breakpointnumber` as stated [here](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbbreak.html#DISABLE).